# Cordova, building for android can not find gradle on Windows 10

Tags: windows, cordova, gradle

Installed Cordova 10 through npm on Windows 10, and I have installed:

- The correct Java JDK
- Android Studio
- In Android Studio => Settings menu, I have added SDK's for all the Android versions from 7 to 11 (API Level 24 to 30)
- I have added environment variables to location of Android Studio in *Path* (... \Appdata\Local\Android\SDK)
- I have added the *ANDROID_SDK_ROOT* and *ANDROID_HOME* environment variables to same location as above
- I have downloaded gradle 6.7.1 and added *D:\gradle-6.7.1* to both Path and GRADLE_HOME environment variable

Still(!) I can not manage to build a basic apk from Cordova sample build, getting the following message:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add *\bin* to the gradle directory in *Path* environment variable, finally it works.